Understanding the titlesec package before and after separator syntax
I am trying to understand the following code:
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{2ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.2ex}

I have read the titlesec document to understand the implementation for the plus and minus keywords, but I only see the following:

If you dislike typing the full skip values, including the plus and minus parameters, an abbreviation *n is provided. In the ⟨before-sep⟩ argument this is equivalent to n ex with some stretchability and a minute shrinkability. In the ⟨after-sep⟩ some stretchability (smaller) and no shrinkability.

I have searched in StackExchange and found many questions that use it but do not explain it.
I would be grateful if someone could describe this syntax, or point me to another document that defines it.

An image should help. I used doubled values (and a shrinking factor also below the title) in order to better see what happens.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\theparagraph}
  {1em}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
  {0pt}
  {4ex plus 2ex minus 1ex}
  {3ex plus 0.4ex minus 0.4ex}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode
\vtop{
  \hsize=0.3\textwidth\raggedright
  \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \paragraph{Title}
  \lipsum[2][1-2]
}\hfil
\vtop spread -30pt{
  \hsize=0.3\textwidth\raggedright
  \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \paragraph{Title}
  \lipsum[2][1-2]
}\hfil
\vtop spread 30pt{
  \hsize=0.3\textwidth\raggedright
  \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \paragraph{Title}
  \lipsum[2][1-2]
}

\end{document}

Don't look too much into the \vtop: the purpose is to show the effect when the same text is typeset under different constraints.

In the first column, the text is typeset at its natural height. Before the title there is a 4ex vertical space and below a 3ex vertical space.
In the middle column I simulated a page where vertical spaces need to be reduced (shrinked) at their maximum: indeed the space is 3ex above and 2.6ex below, as allowed by the minus dimensions.
In the third column, I simulated a page where vertical spaces need to be enlarged (say there's something big on the next page). The plus component is now used, but the space above is allowed to stretch also beyond the “optimal” 6ex (below it's 3.4ex).
When spaces need to be stretched beyond the optimal size, you'll get an “Underfull vbox” message. The middle column results in an “Overfull \vbox, because there is no way to get 30pt of shrinking.
With the exact amount of stretching or shrinking we get no overfull or underfull boxes.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\theparagraph}
  {1em}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
  {0pt}
  {4ex plus 2ex minus 1ex}
  {3ex plus 0.4ex minus 0.4ex}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode
\vtop{
  \hsize=0.3\textwidth\raggedright
  \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \paragraph{Title}
  \lipsum[2][1-2]
}\hfil
\vtop spread -1.4ex{
  \hsize=0.3\textwidth\raggedright
  \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \paragraph{Title}
  \lipsum[2][1-2]
}\hfil
\vtop spread 2.4ex{
  \hsize=0.3\textwidth\raggedright
  \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \paragraph{Title}
  \lipsum[2][1-2]
}

\end{document}


Allowing shrinkable space below is not recommended, but the space above should be stretchable to help in page makeup.
